# Error while updating Triggered Send Defination

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am getting an exception from ExactTarget. I am consuming using SOAP API.

> Exception occurred during [UpdateTriggeredSendDefinition]
>
> ErrorID = 1385792279

Can any one tell what this ErrorID represents?

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: Hello Rama, you'll need to provide more information than that. Are you getting this error when updating the Triggered Send from using the SOAP API, or when using the interface? If you are using the SOAP API, please can you provide an example SOAP request envelope?

Answer (score 0):

The ErrorID is used by SFMC Support to retrieve the error details from the server log.